# Count days remain & days passed from today in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, date, counting

I'm trying to **count days left and days passed** in my database. I have A day for Deadline and a day as Start Day on my table and this counting must compare from #todays date#. In the table I have 10000 records that is impossible to count by hand.

Comment: Please post some sample data, the expected result and what you have tried.

Comment: Dear Burrell, thank you for helps but i can't send any data.i don't have permission to this.sorry

Comment: @emadghasemi I made important changes to second part of my answer. sry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure but I guess what you are looking for is `DATEDIFF()` function.
So your code would be like:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY,[StartDate],GETDATE()) AS CountDaysPassed,
       DATEDIFF(DAY,GETDATE(),[EndDate])  AS CountDaysLeft
FROM MyTable
```

This is if you have **Date** as your start date and deadline (end date).
But If you have **days** (**integer**, like 10 days) as your deadline your calculation should be like:

```
   SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY,GETDATE(),(DATEADD(DAY,[DeadlineDays],[StartDate]))) AS CountDaysLeft
   FROM MyTable
```